# JavaScript cookies - Day of week significance?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm currently fiddling around with setting cookies using JavaScript at the moment but have come across something which is bothering me a little bit.

Let's take this example, which sets the cookie "test" with a value of 12345 a few weeks before the Year 2038 Problem:

```
document.cookie = "test=12345;expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:59:59 GMT;path=/";
```

If I change this date from a Thursday to a Monday, the cookie is still set correctly (at least in Chrome) and will presumably still expire on Thursday 31/12/37. I'm not going to wait to find out.

So, is this day of the week important? Is it something for people to worry about?

Comment: Shouldn't matter. In your console, do `var d= new Date("Mon, 31 Dec 2037 23:59:59")` and check `d` - it's still Thursday

Comment: Oh, neat. ~~~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most browsers it doesn't matter. However you nevertheless can't be sure that all implementations behave that way if you pass them such an invalid timestamp.